# How to get modified Image (img) Source (src) server-side?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

I am stuck on something that is giving me a headache. I am new to ASP.Net and I can't get through something that seems very simple in PHP.

I have an img element that I declare with an empty src attribute :

```
<img runat="server" id="result_img" />
```

On the client-side, I have a script that changes the values of this attribute :

```
var img = $("img[id$='result_img']")[0];
img.src = 'pathToImg';
```

The image is showing well and everything is perfect.

However, when I try to get back this modified value on the server-side like this

```
var urlImage = result_img.Src;
```

the 'Src' attribute is still empty.

Am I doing something wrong or is it something impossible to do in Asp ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I just think the problem is that changing elements' properties in the client (other than `input`s value) doesn't reflect on the server. It's just the way ASP.NET works. I can't think of an immediate solution, but someone will come up with something

Comment: does this work in PHP? I doubt it. You need to explicitly communicate to the server the new URL.

Comment: "When I try to get the modified value on the server-side"... when? On a post-back?

Comment: Maybe you can add a hidden field to your form and put the URL there when you attach the URL to the image.

Comment: @akonsu Well I tried that with an input text but the problem is the image source is a base64 string and depending on the size of the image, it can take some time to write this in an input field. Basically, in my page, the user chooses an image from his computer, this image is then processed with some javascript and the result is stored in the new img element. All I want to do is getting back this image on the server.

Comment: @AurélienC do you mean writing the base64 string representing an image into an `input` field is slow?

Comment: How *exactly* did the server get the updated image information when your server was PHP?  There has to be some sort of explicit communication.

Comment: @akonsu Yes and the user could click on the save button before the writing is done.

Comment: @Pointy My server has never been in PHP, I was just saying that I would have done it easier in this language, maybe not in the same way.

Comment: Well regardless of how the server works, the client code has to issue an HTTP request back to the server to communicate any updates.

Comment: I would then attach an event handler to the click event on the save button, or to the form submission event, and write the image to a hidden field there. Or use AJAX to POST it to the server.

Comment: @akonsu I tried your first solution and it worked like a charm. Thank you very much !

Comment: cool. glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would attach an event handler to the click event on the save button, or to the form submission event, and write the image to a hidden field there. Or use AJAX to POST it to the server.